# Spring dataSource and scope

Tags: spring, hibernate, scope

I have project where DB has been moved into claster.

I have to change my scope from singelton into request.

My configuration with sigelton is:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.userrw}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.userrwpass}" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="validationInterval" value="30000"/>
    <property name="suspectTimeout" value="60"/>
    <property name="jdbcInterceptors" value="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer" />

</bean>
```

When i change:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close" scope="request">
```

i get error:

```
        ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception 
is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still 
receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1385)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1389)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just need one **DataSource** instance per application rather than per request. The reason it fails because Spring is trying to initialize **DataSource** at start up time, at that time there is no request available yet.

So remove **scope="request"**

Comment: OK, so how to create configuration, that connection to DB will be new per query ?

Comment: **SessionFactory** does not represent DB connection, but **Session** does. **SessionFactory** is mapping to underlying DB instance, and **Session** is actually holding physical connection to DB. So back to you question, how to get fresh DB connection per query? You do not need to do anything extra rather than creating a singleton **SessionFactory** (LocalSessionFactoryBean) and get sessionFactory injected into your DAO class and call **getCurrentSession()**. Spring will create a Session instance and bind it with current thread(means request scoped) transparently.

Comment: And I strongly recommend you go through spring doc.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html